# Running simulation in omnet++ with standalone file

Tags: omnet++

I want to run my simulation on a machine that does not have omnet++. Is there any way that I can do that?
Is it possible to build my project in a way to be self sufficient?

Comment: Which operating system do you want to use - Windows, or Linux, or Mac?

Comment: I want to run my simulations on Linux servers.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid dependencies to native `OMNeT++` libraries (e.g. `liboppenvird.so`, `liboppsimd.so` etc) by compiling your `OMNeT++` with **static** libraries option. In order to do that open `configure.user` from main `OMNeT++` directory and set:
`SHARED_LIBS=no`
Then rebuild your OMNeT++ (`make clean`, `./configure`, `make`). Next rebuild your project.
Example for `tictoc`:

```
cd samples/tictoc
opp_makemake -f --deep
make clean && make
```

Then `ldd tictoc` will show:

```
user@ubuntu:/opt/omnetpp-4.6/samples/tictoc$ ldd tictoc
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe4e1f6000)
    libtk8.6.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtk8.6.so (0x00007fcf868d7000)
    libtcl8.6.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtcl8.6.so (0x00007fcf8653a000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fcf8631f000)
    libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007fcf85f56000)
    libmpi_cxx.so.1 => /usr/lib/libmpi_cxx.so.1 (0x00007fcf85d3a000)
    libmpi.so.1 => /usr/lib/libmpi.so.1 (0x00007fcf859b1000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fcf857ad000)
    libhwloc.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhwloc.so.5 (0x00007fcf85568000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fcf85259000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fcf84f51000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fcf84d3b000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fcf84b1d000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fcf84753000)
    libXft.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXft.so.2 (0x00007fcf8453e000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007fcf84300000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007fcf83fc7000)
    libXss.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXss.so.1 (0x00007fcf83dc3000)
    libicuuc.so.52 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.52 (0x00007fcf83a45000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007fcf83842000)
    libltdl.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7 (0x00007fcf83638000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fcf86c2b000)
    libnuma.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnuma.so.1 (0x00007fcf8342d000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007fcf83185000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007fcf82f7b000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007fcf82d52000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007fcf82b33000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007fcf82921000)
    libicudata.so.52 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.52 (0x00007fcf810b4000)
    libpng12.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007fcf80e8e000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007fcf80c8a000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007fcf80a84000)
```

Moreover, if you do not need graphical interface, you can build your project only for command line mode. It decreases number of dependencies. In order to do that use the command:
`opp_makemake -f --deep -u Cmdenv`
(or set it using Project properties in `OMNeT++`). 
After rebuilding `tictoc` there is no dependencies to X11 libraries:

```
user@ubuntu:/opt/omnetpp-4.6/samples/tictoc$ ldd tictoc
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd82197000)
    libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f452e838000)
    libmpi_cxx.so.1 => /usr/lib/libmpi_cxx.so.1 (0x00007f452e61c000)
    libmpi.so.1 => /usr/lib/libmpi.so.1 (0x00007f452e293000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f452e08f000)
    libhwloc.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhwloc.so.5 (0x00007f452de4a000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f452db3b000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f452d833000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f452d61d000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f452d3ff000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f452d035000)
    libicuuc.so.52 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.52 (0x00007f452ccb7000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f452ca9c000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f452c899000)
    libltdl.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7 (0x00007f452c68f000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f452ec01000)
    libnuma.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnuma.so.1 (0x00007f452c484000)
    libicudata.so.52 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.52 (0x00007f452ac17000)
```

Answer (score 1):

OMNET projects need opp_run file (omnet-x.x/bin/opp_run). Basically, opp_run allows starting simulation models that are linked as shared libraries. You can run your simulation using

```
opp_run -r 0 -u Cmdenv -c yourConfigName -n . -l yourProgram params.ini

-r <runnumber> allows you to select runs
-u Cmdenv tells omnetpp to run under Cmdenv (command-line environment)
-c <configname> option is used to select a configuration
-n option is used to specify the NED path
-l option is used to load additional shared libraries
```

opp_run requires many shared libraries to run properly. In Linux, you can use `ldd` to list all the shared libraries required by opp_run. For example on my Ubuntu 14 machine:

[image]

As you can see, opp_run requires many shared libraries and you need to have them all installed on your target machine.

I am also running my OMNET simulation on a Linux server (Ubuntu 14 Server). But I have installed OMNET on my home folder (without any need for sudo access) and can run the simulations using the above command (with this assumption that you have all the required libraries installed). Check OMNET installation [guide](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/InstallGuide.pdf) to check which packages you need on your system.